What are the correct routes to use for Opencart events when using the Journal3 Theme
I made a really simple Opencart Extension, using the event system, and ran it on a test server. It worked with the default theme, so now I am trying to modify it to run on an Opencart server with Jurnal3 installed. Now, when I install it, I get 2 internal server errors. Other nearly identical extensions from other developers install and run fine. So I believe something must be wrong with my event registration.
I am using Opencart 3.0.3.3 and Journal3.
My install function looked like this initially:
public function install()
{
    $this->load->model('setting/event');
    $this->model_setting_event->addEvent('insertheadercode', 'catalog/view/common/header/before', 'extension/module/pagefixes/insertpagestyle');
    $this->model_setting_event->addEvent('inserttwigcode', 'catalog/view/product/product/before', 'extension/module/pagefixes/inserttwigcode');

}


I also tried this:
$this->model_setting_event->addEvent('insertheadercode', ‘catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/common/header/before’, 'extension/module/pagefixes/insertpagestyle');
$this->model_setting_event->addEvent('inserttwigcode', 'catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/product/product/before', 'extension/module/pagefixes/inserttwigcode');


What would be the correct route to register these events for the Journal3 theme?

Watch out for typos. In the line  class ControllerExtensionModuleMyExtension extends Controller { at the top of my controller, I misspelled the file name MyExtension. The default routes seem to be valid for Journal3 at least for the product page.
Like so:
    $this->model_setting_event->addEvent('inserttwigcode', 'catalog/view/product/product/before', 'extension/module/pagefixes/inserttwigcode');

